# customize a youtube video not to go fullscreen on play on mobile

Tags: css, video, responsive-design, html5-video

Is it possible to play a youtube video that is responsive to the mobile device NOT to go full screen after play the play button. In other words play in the div box that is define.

```
<p>
<div class="w3-row w3-padding-0">
    <div id="topleftfadein"  class="w3-col s12 l12 m12 w3-margin-bottom animated fadeInLeft slower w3-white">
        <div class="videoWrapperOuter">
        <div id="yt1" class="videoWrapperInner">
    <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/TMEmv9uienU?autoplay=1&modestbranding=1&controls=0"
    frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add `&playsinline=1` to your iframe `src`, as per YouTube's [IFrame Player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#playsinline)